# Firebase 9.0.0 enum deserialize missing constructor error

Tags: java, android, serialization, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using an enum field in my model which looks like

```
@JsonProperty("status")
public Status getStatus() {
    return status;
}

@JsonProperty("status")
public void setStatus(Status status) {
    this.status = status;
}
```

Previously when firebase used jackson. It worked fine.

Now it serializes enums as such

```
--status
   |
   --value: "OPEN"
```

But when it deserializes, it is showing an error as

```
com.mypackage.app.models.Order$Status is missing a constructor with no arguments
```

With jackson I was using annotations to customize serialization/deserialization.

This is how `Status` enum looks like

```
public enum Status {

    OPEN, ACKNOWLEDGED, CONFIRMED, CANCELED, COMPLETED;

    Status() {
    }

    String value;


    @JsonValue
    public String getValue() {
       // return this.ordinal();
        return this.name();
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static Status fromValue(String statusString) {
        for (Status c : Status.values()) {
            if (c.name().equals(statusString)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Status type code: " + statusString);
    }

}
```